# Android - connecting to Wifi without security regulations (no WEP/WPA/WPA2)

Tags: android, wifi

I tried to establish a connection to an unsecured Access point, but it always creates a new profile with WPA2.

```
            ap_ssid = "\"AP_SSID\"";
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }

            config = new WifiConfiguration();
            config.SSID = ap_ssid;
            config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        

            int netID = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netID, true);
```

Comment: why the quotes around the SSID?  (Just curious, seems odd and incorrect) s/b just `ap_ssid = "AP_SSID";`

Answer (score 0):

```
config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE);
```